# GBM in r for coxph loss function

Tags: r, predict, gbm

I am using gbm in r to predict survival (distribution = "coxph").

The predicted values when gbm.predict(...., type = "response") are ranging between [-0.001 to 0.5] approximately.

How can I interpret the risk of a new sample without having risks ranging from 0 to 1 ([0,1]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at bazehaz.gbm you will see that gbm.predict gives the lambda_0(t).

```
The proportional hazard model assumes h(t|x)=lambda(t)*exp(f(x)).
gbm can estimate the f(x) component via partial likelihood.
After estimating f(x), basehaz.gbm can compute the a nonparametric estimate of lambda(t).
```

So you can go like this (I hope):

```
model = gbm(Surv(durata, status2015) ~ .-fold, data= ...)
XB =predict.gbm(model, n.trees = ..., type = "response")

lambda0 = basehaz.gbm(t = data$time, delta = data$censoring,  t.eval =   sort(unique(data$time)), cumulative = FALSE, f.x = XB , smooth=T)
XBnew =predict.gbm(model, n.trees = ..., data=newData, type = "response")

hazard = h(t|x)= lambda0*exp(XBnew).
```

If you're looking for the survival function.. I'm working on it. :)

P.S.: There is a strange behaviour in the estimation of XB thought.. since it changes significantly with the number of trees. :(

Comment: I tried your approach, why XB and XBnew are same, even if I use data differently

Comment: Has this been fixed? I'm interested in predicting the survival function. Thanks!

Comment: If I add the test variable to the result of the call to `predict`, it seems I'm getting something meaningful (?)... That is: `X.pred <- X.test + predict(model, ..., type="response")`. In my test case, I'm getting excellent prediction, and I'm not sure if it's suspicious or not...